# How can I create a factory of Upgradeable smart contracts?

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts, contract-upgrading

I'm using OpenZeppelin hardhat plugin to deploy proxy contracts and I was asking myself how to achieve the same thing but from a contract. So for example I want to have a ProxyContractFactory that can create Proxy contracts, so this is the structure:

```
ProxyContractFactory ---- ProxyContract1 ------> Implementation1OfProxy1
                    |---- ProxyContract2 ------> Implementation1OfProxy2
                                        |------> Implementation2OfProxy2
```

and so on...
Can you point me to any documentation that can help me understand this? Thank you in advance.